# the development server returned response error code 500

Tags: android, google-maps, react-native

I ran the following code in adding a mapview to android in react native.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { MapView } from 'react-native-maps'
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native'

export default class MapTest extends Component {

   constructor() {
      super();
   }
   render() {
      return (
        <MapView
           style = {styles.map}
           showsUserLocation = {false}
           followUserLocation = {false}
           zoomEnabled = {true}
        />
      );
   }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
   map: {
      height: 400,
      marginTop: 80
   }
})
AppRegistry.registerComponent('MapTest', () => MapTest);
```

but I get 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fy7oe.png) error.
 I don't know how to solve. please help.

Comment: Seems like a problem with one of your nodejs modules

Comment: @Denny how can I fix it?

Comment: From what I see in the error, install the `module-resolver` package in your nodejs server

Comment: @Denny it doesn't work